# Rate of neutrino generation in Earth's core?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, earth, neutrinos

I know that there are radioactive elements present in the Earth's core, but has anyone determined how much?  That is, do we have an estimate of the number of neutrinos per second generated within the Earth (i.e., due to radioactive decay processes)?

Comment: There's actually [a neat Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_internal_heat_budget) for this. Several references inside; I've never read, though.

Comment: you might be interested in this review https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.09321.pdf

Comment: @annav - Thanks for the link.  I figured someone must have looked into this and oddly I never thought to search for geoneutrino :(  This is a tome, wow...